# Creating simple carved animal heads?

Tags: modeling, mesh

Another very specific question: How would you approach modelling this shape?

I have 0 experience with animal/organic shapes like this so it's a bit outside my wheelhouse.

If anyone with experience would be able to suggest a simple approach for making carved styles like this, I'd really appreciate it.

Cheers.

[image: Panther head]

Comment: Hello, draw all the lines you see, extrude, pull the edges, etc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Draw the lines of your shape with some edges:

[image]

Extrude the shape, mirror:

[image]

Pull the edges that are supposed to come forwards, etc:

[image]

Comment: That's got pretty much exactly what I was looking for. Thank you. :) 

Does it actually matter too much how neat the geo is? I *TRY* to not use ngons but since everything gets triangulated I've seen people who say it doesn't really matter...

Comment: if it doesn't create bad shading or artefacts, it's ok